# How can I convert speeds in my code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, converters

I have a task to create a program that detects the number plates that are both **foreign** and **speeding**. For this, a section of the road, elapsed times etc had to be created. The problem of the code isn't with how unrealistic the speeds are, but the fact that I found out from my teacher recently that the speeds are supposed to be in **miles per hour**, not **metres per second**.

```
import re

# DATA
distance = 0.06 # Distance between the Camera A and B; 0.06 = 600 metres
speed_limit = 20 # (meters per second)

number_plates = ["DV61 GGB",      #UK
                 "D31 EG 2A",     #F
                 "5314 10A02",    #F
                 "24TEG 5063",    #F
                 "TR09 TRE",      #UK
                 "524 WAL 75",    #F
                 "TR44 VCZ",      #UK
                 "FR52 SWD",      #UK
                 "100 GBS 12",    #F
                 "HG55 BPO"       #UK
                 ]

enter = [7.12,7.17,7.22,7.12,7.23,7.41,7.18,7.25,7.11,7.38]
leave = [7.56,7.39,7.49,7.56,7.45,7.57,7.22,7.31,7.59,7.47]

# Find the non-UK plates
pattern = "(?![A-Z]{2}\d{2}\s+[A-Z]{3}$)"
foreign_numbers = list(filter(lambda x: re.match(pattern, x), number_plates))

# Calculations for speed
elapsed = [(l - e)/100 for l, e in zip(leave, enter)]
speed = [distance/t for t in converted_elapsed]

# Dictionary for foreign speeders + 2 conditions
foreign_speeders = {plate: speed 
                    for plate, speed in zip(number_plates, speed)
                    if (plate in foreign_numbers) and (speed > speed_limit)}

print("10 cars have passed Camera A, then Camera B\nSpeed limit is 20 meters per second.\n")

# Write foreign speeders to file
for plate, speed in foreign_speeders.items():

    speeders_data = open("speeders.txt","w") # Opens file with name of "speeders.txt"
    speeders_data.write(
        "{0:>13s} is foreign and is speeding at{1:5.1f} mps, and has an excess speed of {2:3.1f} mps.".format(plate, speed, speed-speed_limit))
    speeders_data = open("speeders.txt","r")
    print(speeders_data.read())
    speeders_data.close()
```

I wonder, would it be simpler to re-write all speed variables, for example `speed_limit` and the items of `elapsed` & formula of `speed` in their converted forms, or to convert the speed in the middle of the code?

Whichever solution seems more suitable, how can I do it?

Comment: It depends on how much code you must rewrite and how much you are afraid to break things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a function such as:

```
def mps_to_mph(mps):
    return 2.23694 * mps
```

and then use it in your for loop:

```
speed = map(mps_to_mph, speed)
speed_limit = mps_to_mph(speed_limit)
```

You can leave the calculations and thresholding in meters per second and only convert for the display.

Comment: Not sure whether I'm doing this right, but I got an error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "M:\ICT Coursework\Task 2.1.py", line 32, in <module>
    speed = mps_to_mph(speed)
  File "M:\ICT Coursework\Task 2.1.py", line 23, in mps_to_mph
    return 2.23694 * mps
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'`

Comment: Oh I didn't notice, your speed variable is in fact a list, I edited the answer to work for a list of speeds, but judging by that format string you have in your for loop, I think you don't want to do that, but rather you want to iterate over values of speed.

Comment: I'm getting another error. `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "M:\ICT Coursework\Task 2.1.py", line 33, in <module>
    speed_limit = map(mps_to_mph, speed_limit)
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`

Comment: Right :D sorry. Only the speed was a `list`, the other one is an `int`, so the map is not necessary there

Answer (score 1):

As a start, you definitely need a function which can convert units, e.g. `mps_to_mph` as @mirosval suggested.

However, I suggest you should make it more obvious what the unit is at some point.
Simplest solution is to have it in variable name: `speed_mps = 78.7`, `speed_mph = mps_to_mph(speed_mps)`, otherwise you will not be able to understand your code when you read it again (well, you might never read *this* code again, but at least your teacher will... and every code you ever write should be easy to understand without additional explanations).

In a more complex application, with many such calculations, you might want to have a class which can remember units and knows how to convert values, so that you can do something like:

```
speed = Speed(78.8, 'm/s')
if speed > Speed(60, 'mph'):
    # something
```